# Allow quoted values in mysql integer columns?

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1067

Consider the table schema for table1:

```
id: int
country_id: int
description: varchar(50)
```

and the query:

```
INSERT INTO table1(id, country_id, description) VALUES (1, '20', 'Test Desc');
```

This would work under MySQL 4x but will fail under MySQL 5x (ERROR 1067 (42000): Invalid default value for .. ").

I know the reason for this to happen - **country_id** is **int** and therefore should not be quoted. Is there a mysql switch under 5x somewhere to make it behave like 4x so the query won't fail?

I've inherited an application that uses queries like this and I'm looking for a quick fix until I can find the time to fix all the queries.

Thank you

Comment: Are you sure it's not that you have an auto-increment field that you also have a default for?  They eliminated that in 5.

Comment: Or are you using '' as a default value for an int?  You have to use 0 or NULL now.

Comment: My apologies, on closer look it seems like the query insert '' for the int field.

Comment: the default for the int column is 0

Answer (score 1):

There is no problem with '20'. MySql (5.x) also casts '20' to 20 and => this is a valid insert